# How to filter folders(Directories and Sub-Dir) based on specific file's extension in java..?

Tags: java, file, filter, directory

Okay i read a lot of stuff and i failed to figure out that how to filter folders(directories and sub-dir) based on file's extension for example i want the list of folders(Directories and Sub-dir) that contains only ".mp3" or ".mp4" files and i don't want to use Walk.Tree, if there's any possible way through "filenameFilter" or any other way except Walk.tree method.

this is the code that i have tried so far, no error but also not filtering specific file's folders. it shows all the folders.

Thanks in Advance.

```
  File[] ff = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3") || new File(dir.toPath().toString(),name).isDirectory();
                }

            });
```

Comment: Ok. If this is the directory structure: dir1-dir11-a.mp3, dir1-dir12-b.txt , what is that you want to output?

Comment: i want the directories that contain only mp3 files for example if the dir11,dir12 contain mp3 file and others don't then i want only dir11,dir12.

Comment: Yes but in my example. What is the output you want? Only dir11 or both dir1 and dir11

Comment: Yes both dir1 and dir11 if the dir1 is parent and sub dir2345678910, dir11

Comment: Do you need these names in the hierarchical order or just a set of those folder names?

Comment: I am thinking of a Tree implementation , will that work for you? The tree will have nodes as folders and the leaves will hold only mp3 files, and there wont be any folder node which is a leaf

Comment: in the hierarchical order

Comment: actually i am developing folder library for my mp3 player and Walk.tree need api 26 so that why i don't want to use Walk.tree or apache.io

Comment: plz check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple console application.

The algorithm goes like this:

1. First recursively search from specified root folder for all files with mp3 extension and keep adding them to a list.
2. If this list happens to be empty, return.
3. Else, for each of these mp3 files, recursively find their parent folders until you reach root folder and keep storing these parent folders in a set to avoid duplicate search.
4. Now print out all those valid folders starting from root.

```
public class MyApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File rootDir = new File("src/main/resources/dir1");
    List<File> filesListWithValidExtension = new ArrayList<>();
    recursiveSearch(rootDir, filesListWithValidExtension);

    if (filesListWithValidExtension.size() == 0) {
      System.out.println("Specified root directory has no file with mp3 extension");
      return;
    }

    Set<File> requiredFolders = new HashSet<>();
    for (File fileWithValidExtension : filesListWithValidExtension) {
      File parent;
      do {
        parent = fileWithValidExtension.getParentFile();
        if (requiredFolders.contains(parent)) {
          break;
        } else {
          requiredFolders.add(parent);
          fileWithValidExtension = parent;
        }
      }
      while (!parent.getPath().equals(rootDir.getPath()));
    }

    System.out.println("Printing folders (from root) containing mp3 files");
    recursivePrint(rootDir, requiredFolders);

  }

  private static void recursiveSearch(File file, List<File> filesListWithvalidExtension) {
    if (!file.exists()) {
      return;
    }
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
        recursiveSearch(f, filesListWithvalidExtension);
      }
    }
    if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3")) {
      filesListWithvalidExtension.add(file);
    }
  }

  private static void recursivePrint(File file, Set<File> requiredFolders) {
    if (!requiredFolders.contains(file)) {
      return;
    }
    System.out.println(file.getPath());

    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
      recursivePrint(f, requiredFolders);
    }

  }

}
```

This program outputs like:

```
Printing folders (from root) containing mp3 files
src/main/resources/dir1
src/main/resources/dir1/dir12
src/main/resources/dir1/dir11
src/main/resources/dir1/dir11/dir111
```

Comment: i tried but stack overflow said "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: ohh it's ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: by the way i am new here and  again Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: Happy to help :-)